# Not able to use the AWS ECR image properly in ArogCD

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, argocd

I have created a CI pipeline using GitHub actions and it is creating a docker image and updating its tag and pushing it to AWS ECR. I also have helm charts in the same repo which I am using to deploy pods on AWS EKS using ArgoCD. I am also updating my helm chart value.yaml file with a new image tag version on a successful build.

When I am trying to deploy a pod on EKS using ArgoCD. I am facing an issue.

Issue: I am able to see my ECR repo URL and the latest version in the parameter during creation but when I create it. I am not able to see my tag with my ECR repo. Instead of a tag, there is just some random number, and ArgoCD trying to pull that image from ECR which is not available ultimately and I got an error.

So, I tried a couple of things but was not able to solve it if anyone knows any solution then please reply.

I am attaching my value.yaml, GitHub actions workflow yaml and error screenshots.

Values.yml (Helm chart file)

```
# Default values for automation-chart.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare variables to be passed into your templates.

replicaCount: 1

image:
  repository: <repo_id>.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/<repo_name>
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  version: master-b71dbh4

imagePullSecrets: []
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

serviceAccount:
  # Specifies whether a service account should be created
  create: false
  # Annotations to add to the service account
  annotations: {}
  # The name of the service account to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name: ""

podAnnotations: {}

podSecurityContext: {}
  # fsGroup: 2000

securityContext: {}
  # capabilities:
  #   drop:
  #   - ALL
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  # runAsNonRoot: true
  # runAsUser: 1000

service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  port: 8080

ingress:
  enabled: false
  className: ""
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local

resources: {}
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  # limits:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi
  # requests:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi

autoscaling:
  enabled: false
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 100
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
  # targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 80

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}
```

GitHub actions CI yaml file:

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build and Pushing the Image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build and tag image 
      id: build-image
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: <repo_name>

      run: |
        # Build a docker container and push it to ECR
        git_hash=$(git rev-parse --short "$GITHUB_SHA")
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:${GITHUB_REF##*/}-$git_hash .
        echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:${GITHUB_REF##*/}-$git_hash"
        echo "::set-output name=tag::$git_hash"

    - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
      id: meta
      uses: docker/metadata-action@v4.1.1
      with:
        images: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}/${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY }}


    - name: Push image to Amazon ECR
      id: push-image
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: gitops-argocd

      run: |
        echo "Pushing image to ECR..."
        git_hash=$(git rev-parse --short "$GITHUB_SHA")
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:${GITHUB_REF##*/}-$git_hash
        echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:${GITHUB_REF##*/}-$git_hash"

    - name: Update Version
      run: |
          git_hash=$(git rev-parse --short "$GITHUB_SHA")
          version=$(cat ./charts/automation-chart/values.yaml | grep version: | awk '{print $2}')
          sed -i "s/$version/${GITHUB_REF##*/}-$git_hash/" ./charts/automation-chart/values.yaml

    - name: Commit and push changes
      uses: devops-infra/action-commit-push@v0.4
      with:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.SECRET_GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        commit_message: Version updated
```

Here is the image which i am getting during creation:

[image]

This the screenshot in which i am getting images name as:

[image]

As you can see in the picture there is some random number 1.16.0 instead of image version/ If anyone know the solution ti this issue. please reply.

Thanks

Comment: what are the values of ${GITHUB_REF##*/} and $git_hash